# Input long phrase in file with C++

Tags: c++, file, input, output

I' m training with file in C++. I have a  problem: If I write more than 1 word in the terminal, in the file I have just the first written word.

*Example*

> Hello devs

in the file I will have only

> Hello

and the next time, that I'll execute the programme the new word will be in the next row.

**Code**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */

main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string test;
    string st;

    ofstream biblio;
    biblio.open("lis.txt", ios::app);

    if(biblio.is_open()){
        cout <<" Write in file: ";
        cin >> test;
        biblio << test << "\n";
        biblio.close();
        cout<<"I'm in the if!!!\n";
    }

    ifstream biblio1;
    biblio1.open("list.txt");
    if(biblio1.is_open()){
        while(getline(biblio1,st)){
            cout << st << '\n';
        }
        cout<<"I'm in the other if!!!\n";
        biblio1.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Not possible to open the file\n";
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `cin >> test`, only reads one word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

operator `>>` uses white space to delineate items, use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)`(std::cin, test)` instead.